# Simple OpenGL ES Shader in Libgdx Output is white should be red

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, shader

I want to use a simple shader in my 2D-libgdx-project, using OpenGL ES. I've never used OpenGL ES before, so maybe my headers are not right?

Vertex-Shader:

```
in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 passTextureCoords;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
    passTextureCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

Fragment-Shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

in vec2 passTextureCoords;

out vec4 outColour;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main(void)
{
    // Get color at coordinate by sampler and output it
//    outColour = texture(textureSampler, passTextureCoords);
//  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    outColour = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Actually I've used OpenGL 3+ quite often in the past, but never alongside Libgdx and never OpenGL ES.

What this shader should do: Take each pixel and return red instead. But all I get is white.

I create it like this:

```
 private ShaderProgram shader;

 this.shader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("shaders/test.vertex").readString(), Gdx.files.internal("shaders/test.fragment").readString());
 this.shader.pedantic = false;
```

and render like that:

```
public void render(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.setShader(this.shader);
    model.render(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.setShader(null);
    outline.render(spriteBatch);
}
```

All I get is white for the model, not red. So I guess something is wrong. I do not want to specify any more uniforms, so I've set pedantic to false. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libgdx still uses OpenGL ES 2.0, so the shaders need different keywords. (This was changed in OpenGL ES 3.0 so it more closely matches OpenGL 3.x, but Libgdx doesn't fully support that yet.)

- Replace keyword `in` in the vertex shader with `attribute`.
- Replace keyword `out` in the vertex shader with `varying`.
- Replace keyword `in` in the fragment shader with `varying`.
- Remove `outColour` and use the built-in `gl_FragColor`

Additionally, you have to use the attribute names that SpriteBatch is expecting so your attributes must be `a_position`, `a_texCoord0`, and if you need it `a_color`. And likewise your uniform has to be what SpriteBatch is using so change `textureSampler` to `u_texture`.

And I saw you calling the function `texture` in your commented out code, but in OpenGL ES 2.0, you need to use the function `texture2D` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this helps, still no good shader tho. I mean, I get a huge red rectangle now, that is way off the place where it should be rendered.

Comment: What are your model's coordinates? Seems a bit odd to me that you're using SpriteBatch to render a "model" and that you're not using a defined projection. The default projection is an orthographic view of (-1,-1) to (1,1) looking down the -Z axis.

Comment: @Teolha , as an alternative to tenfour04's awnser ,you can  enable opengl es 3.0,the latest versions support it and if your hardware support it too you will not have any problem.(cfg.useGL30=true; to the ApplicationConfiguration when creating the desktop or android start classes)

Comment: @SteveL @Teolha You would also need to add `#version 300 es` at the top of both shaders. This approach would highly limit compatible Android devices.